# Access user profile from cron

Tags: php, facebook, sdk, cron, access-token

I am building an app that imports friends data into a local database and it's working fine.

I am trying to create a script that is run by a daily cron that will iterate through the user profiles in the local database and updates the friend data.

I am using the PHP SDK.

I have enabled the depreacte_offline_access flag.

Does this mean the access token will automatically expire in 60 days or do I need to do anything else?

If a user signes out of the app or facebook in the same browser can I still retrieve the profile data from the cron script?

Am I correct in thinking that all I need to do is retrive the access token with:

```
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
```

then store it in a database and then set the access token with:

```
$facebook->setAccessToken($new_access_token);
```

and then retieve the profile with

```
$facebook->getUser('/me');
```

?

Also how can I view the expiration date of the access token?

Below is a script to iterate through and retreive profiles but if I run it in the browser it only works for the current signed in user or I get the exception "OAuthException: Error validating access token: The session is invalid because the user logged out. "

```
<?php
require_once(THEME_INCLUDES_PATH . 'facebook.php');

$config = array();
$config['appId'] = APP_ID;
$config['secret'] = APP_SECRET;
$config['fileUpload'] = false; // optional

$facebook = new Facebook($config);

$sql = "SELECT `access_token` FROM `fb_user`";
$result = $db1->db_query($sql);

while($details = $db1->db_fetch_array($result)){

    if($details['access_token']){

        $facebook->setAccessToken($details['access_token']);
        $fb_user = $facebook->getUser('/me');

        if($fb_user){

            try {
                $fb_profile = $facebook->api('/me');        
                print_r( $fb_profile);
            }

            catch (FacebookApiException $e){
                echo $e;
                $fb_user = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no way of doing what you want now that the offline_access got deprecated.

The idea is that your app only has access to the user data when the user actually interacts with your application.
The access token is valid for about 60 days (depending on how you get it), but it can get invalidated due to all kind of reasons (such as user removes your app, changes password, and many more).

When that happens, or the expiration dates arrives, there's nothing that you can do in order to get a new token, unless of course the user reengages your app and then you can get a new token or extend the one you have.

You'll have to make all of the data updating when the user actually interacts with your app and not later on.

In the [official post about the deprecation of the offline_access](http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/) it says:

> The user must access your application before you're able to get a
>   valid "authorization code" to be able to make the server-side OAuth
>   call again. Apps will not be able to setup a background/cron job that
>   tries to automatically extend the expiration time, because the
>   "authorization code" is short-lived and will have expired.

---

## Edit

The official post: [Removal of offline_access Permission](http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/) describes a new endpoint to extend valid access tokens, in one of two cases: If the app got the token from a [client-side flow](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/client-side/) or with a signed request:

> Using the new endpoint below, you will be able to extend the
>   expiration time of an existing, valid access_token. If the
>   access_token was originally generated from a client-side OAuth call or
>   through a signed_request, the endpoint will actually return a new
>   access_token.

It also states that:

> If the access_token is generated from a server-side OAuth call, the
>   resulting access_token will have the longer expiration time.

So my advise is simple to use the [server-side flow](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/) to generate the access token.

As for a list of token invalidating events, they don't have a complete list, but you can find info about it in the same page:

> **Handling expired tokens, user password changes, uninstalled apps, and
>   user logout**
>
> Regardless if your app requested the offline_access permission, apps
>   should gracefully handle an expired access tokens in situations where
>   a user changes their password, deauthorizes an app, or logs out. More
>   information on these cases including a simple code solution that leads
>   to a uniform user experience can be found in this [blog post](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/05/13/how-to--handle-expired-access-tokens/).

And you can check this doc: [Handling Invalid and Expired Access Tokens](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/access-token-expiration/).

Comment: That's basically right, but the token can be invalidated due to other reasons (as I mentioned in my answer).

Comment: What I understood from that is that once a user has got a valid access tokem from the site, a cron script will be a able to access their profile but not renew the expiration time of the access token. So the main problem is that enabling offline_access flag does not seem to automatically make the expiration date last for 60 days and I'm unsure what I need to do? And the other thing is there does not seem to be a fully documented list of events that can cause the access token to become invalid.

Comment: Don't delete your comments, it just makes it confusing to who ever reads it later. I edited my answer with more info.

Comment: I fixed the issue with tokens expiring within 2 hours and not the 60 days by removing my app within facebook and authorising it again.

Comment: more detail and examples http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13217564/facebook-php-post-to-fan-page-with-cronjob