# Graph API and Dynamic Access Tokens

Tags: facebook-graph-api, access-token, facebook-access-token

So basically im making an app which i need to embed a custom facebook wall feed into. I just want a JSONP response... that is all.

From reading for days on access token's e.c.t. i've come to the conclusion there is no way to use the graph API without a valid access token, however i dont want to require the user to login (the target platform doesn't lend itself to easy character input, plus id have to create a custom popup keyboard and interaction JS).

So the only option i've found is to use the access token for the app i setup in facebook. However i do not want to distribute the app secret so i can use the `APP_ID|APP_SECRET` method i've seen method (whatever it is exactly) as that would mean bad things i presume?

So my idea is, to create a proxy script on a server, which will hold the app secret e.c.t. This script will ask FB for an access token, and pass that back to my app so my app can get the wall feed and continue to use that token for refreshing the feed.

If i open my app and get an access token, then another person opens my app and gets an access token, will my access token expire as a new one has been generated? Or can you generate as many access tokens for the same app as you like?

Or can anyone think of a better approach?

**WORKFLOW**

1. User opens app on device (the device is a bespoke contained unit, think of a Raspberry Pi but 100x simpler, and its plugged into a tv)
2. The app loads a number of feeds into area's on the page, these feeds include facebook wall feed from a specific profile.
3. The app will run unattended for days/weeks/months and refresh the feeds of information periodically.

**FB Access Token Workflow**

Since the user cannot login, i need to provide an access token. I do not want to pass round my app secret for the sake of security. So my idea is to use a php proxy script hosted on my server to get the access tokens. Like so:

1. On first load the app with run a function which does an ajax call to my php proxy script requesting a token
2. My proxy script will fire off a request to facebook with my app id and secret, and get a access token back from FB
3. My proxy script will then dump that access token back as a jsonp response to the app
4. The app will grab the access token from the jsonp response, and store it
5. The app will use the retrieved & stored token for all wall feed requests to the facebook graph api.
6. If app detects its token for some reason doesn't work, it will attempt to get a new one from my token proxy script.

That is my idea for how a token proxy script could be used to give access tokens to everyone, without giving away information which would cause issues if someone looked at the app source code (which wouldn't be difficult at all). However if facebook deletes old tokens every time you request a new one, this wouldn't work. So that is the immediate question.

However if theres a better way around the issue, my ears are open. Thanks

Comment: Your question, or i mean the way you explain the question seems a bit complex. Can you please mention the workflow of how this is going to be working? Like, 1. user comes to your site. 2. blah blah. so and so.

Comment: @Kishor: Ive added some extra information on the app process and the proposed token fetching idea. Hopefully it helps clear things up?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you would be able to do what you want with an App access token.

1) App access token doesnt have access to everything that the user has access to, or what you can access using user_access token. Like, some age restricted pages, so and so.

2) Quoting from the documentation :

> Note that the app access token is for **publishing** purposes permitted by
>   the publish_actions and publish_stream permissions. You will be **unable
>   to retrieve information about the status update post with the given ID
>   using the app access token.** Instead, you should use a **user access**
>   token for such purposes.

3) The retrieval ability using app access_token is limited to,

```
a.Basic Profile Info of a User (ID, Name, Username, Gender).

b.A User’s Friends and their IDs.

c.Permissions granted by the User to your App(probably includes email, etc etc.)
```

So, I am not sure if its going to work for what you are looking for. But if you can have the user login first, and make the user go through the auth(he wont need to login) once every 60 days, you can use **extended user access_tokens.**

If you are going that way, this will help. Its some other question I answered dealing with a cronjob. Read : [Facebook PHP post to fan page with cronjob?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13217564/facebook-php-post-to-fan-page-with-cronjob/13284731#13284731)

Hope this helps