# Retrieving Facebook FanPage insights in a cron

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, cron

I'm trying to create a cron job with a php script for retrieving info about stats of a Fan Pages and I have some questions:

have I to log a user to get the access token and use the Facebook API? 
Which kind of token must to use? App token? Page Token?

I've read in several posts in Stackoverflow that only the Page Access token is necessary, but I have no success:

Request: /419788471442322/?fields=access_token
Response: Unsupported get request.

This is the code

```
    //get the app access token         
    $facebook->setAccessToken($facebook->getAccessToken());

    //Format the api call
    $fields = array('access_token');
    $page_info = $facebook->getInsights($id,"",$fields);
    //display the result
    print_r($page_info);


public function getInsights($id, $nameapi, $fields = array(), $limit = null)
{
    if (isset($fields)) $fields = implode(",",$fields);
    if (isset($limit)) $limit = "&limit=".$limit;   

    try {
        echo '/'.$id.'/'.$nameapi.'?fields='.$fields.$limit;
        $fbdata = $this->facebook->api('/'.$id.'/'.$nameapi.'?fields='.$fields.$limit);
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        $fbdata = $e->getMessage();
    }

    return $fbdata;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the App Access Token will be used and you don´t need to set it with setAccessToken.

The App Access Token is good enough for basic infos and the Page feed, but for getting access to the Insights you need a Page Access Token and that´s a bit more complicated. Actually, in a Cron Job you would need a Page Access Token that is valid forever, basic ones are only valid for 2 hours. "Extended Page Access Token" is exactly what you need.

More info about Access Tokens and how to get an Extended Page Access Token:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: Thank you, I will investigate Extended Page Access Token.
I found a very good post too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13217564/facebook-php-post-to-fan-page-with-cronjob?rq=1

Comment: In a few words, I have to get the Page Access Token and then, extend it.
The problem is when I try to get the Page Access Token, the response is 
Request: /419788471442322/?fields=access_token Response: Unsupported get request.

Comment: what´s that page id? i cannot even access it, are you admin of that page? is it unpublished or restricted by age or countries?